# BULK INSERT con un registro que ya existe

Tags: sql, sql-server

En mi tabla target, donde quiero insertar los registros de mi archivo de texto, ya existe el registro con primary key EDF010.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo de texto tengo las siguientes filas:

```
EDF800,New Pradera,Zepita 123,L-01,450,430,Perímetro de Lima,EST001
EDF900,New Oh Sol,Malecón Checa 357,L-14,178,158,Perímetro de Lima,EST001
EDF010,New Nogal,Josè Pizarro,L-21,246,226,Perímetro de Lima,EST001
```

Hay forma de validar los registros duplicados para que no se inserten solo los duplicados y no arroje el error?

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 15
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__EDIFICIO__CE4324755BE55BAA'. Cannot insert duplicate key in 
object 'Renta.EDIFICIOS'. The duplicate key value is (EDF010).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No desde el `BULK INSERT`. Lo que puedes hacer:

1. Desde el `BULK INSERT` insertar todo en una tabla temporal
2. Desde la tabla temporal, insertar solo las filas cuyo `COD_EFIF` no existiera.

Algo así:

```
# Creamos una tabla idéntica a la física
# A modo de ejemplo solo es que solo tiene una columna
CREATE TABLE #Temporal (COD_EDIF VARCHAR(13))

BULK INSERT #Temporal FROM 'archiv.txt' WITH (FieldTerminator = ',', RowTerminator ='')
```

Y ahora, teniendo la temporal es todo más sencillo:

```
INSERT INTO EDIFICIOS(COD_EDIF)
SELECT COD_EDIF
       FROM #Temporal
       WHERE COD_EDIF NOT IN (SELECT COD_EDIF FROM EDIFICIOS)
```

#### Comentario Final:

En realidad, creo que te mentí con respecto al `BULK INSERT`, ya que según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) habría una forma, que es usando el modificador `MAXERRORS`, no lo he usado nunca ni lo haría, pero en los sitios de SO muchos lo plantean como una alternativa, darle a `MAXERRORS` un valor bien alto para ignorar cualquier error por duplicado y eventualmente cualquier otro.